# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT

Tags: php, post, laravel-5, eloquent, get

I want to store the values to the Database and redirect to a new page but find this error. I changed my code many times but same error is displayed.
I am continuously finding this error.Please if there is any tricks to avoid the error please provide it to me.I have tried many possible things but the error is same.Any changes are not helping here.

Route.php

```
            Route::get('/create',   ['as'=>'creates','uses'=>'CAsController@create2']);
            Route::put('/postca', 'CAsController@storing');
```

CAsController

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\CAModel;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   class CAsController extends Controller
    {
    public function create2(){
    return view('chartered.create');
}
public function storing(Request $request)
{
    // Handle File Upload
    if($request->hasFile('profile')){
        // Get filename with the extension
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('profile')->getClientOriginalName();
        // Get just filename
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // Get just ext
        $extension = $request->file('profile')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // Filename to store
        $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        // Upload Image
        $path = $request->file('profile')->storeAs('public/profile', $fileNameToStore);
    } else {
        $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
    }


    // Handle File Upload
    if($request->hasFile('certificate')){
        // Get filename with the extension
        $filenameWithExt1 = $request->file('certificate')->getClientOriginalName();
        // Get just filename
        $filename1 = pathinfo($filenameWithExt1, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // Get just ext
        $extension1 = $request->file('certificate')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // Filename to store
        $fileNameToStore1= $filename1.'_'.time().'.'.$extension1;
        // Upload Image
        $path1 = $request->file('certificate')->storeAs('public/certificate', $fileNameToStore1);
    } else {
        $fileNameToStore1 = 'noimage.jpg';
    }

    $ca = new CAModel;
    $ca->fname = $request->input('fname');
    $ca->lastname = $request->input('lastname');
    $ca->username = $request->input('username');
    $ca->city = $request->input('city');
    $ca->state = $request->input('state');
    $ca->zip = $request->input('zip');
    $ca->phone = $request->input('phone');
    $ca->email = $request->input('email');
    $ca->gstno = $request->input('gstno');
    $ca->website = $request->input('website');
    $ca->services = $request->input('services');
    $ca->profile = $fileNameToStore;
    $ca->certificate = $fileNameToStore1;  
    $ca->save();
    return redirect('/postca');
}
```

}

```
          <form action="/postca" method="POST">
        @method('PUT')
      @csrf
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="UserName" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <label for="city">City</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="City" required> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <label for="state">State</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state" id="state" placeholder="State" required> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <label for="zip">Zip</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" name="zip" placeholder="Zip" required> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <label for="gstno">GST No</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gstno" name="gstno" placeholder="GST number" required>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <label for="website">Website</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="website" name="website" placeholder="GST number" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="services">Select the Services you provide</label>
            <select multiple class="form-control" name="services" id="services" multiple>
              <option>Propertiership</option>
              <option>One Person Company</option>
              <option>Limited Liability Partnership</option>
              <option>Private Limited Company</option>
              <option>Public Limited Company</option>
            </select>
          </div> 
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="custom-file">
                          <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="profile" name="profile" required>
                          <label class="custom-file-label" for="profile">Profile Photo</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
              </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="custom-file">
                      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="certificate" name="certificate" required>
                      <label class="custom-file-label" for="certificate">Company Incorporation Certifcate</label>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Go!">
          </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting your browser cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you return `return redirect('/postca');`. The error comes from the fact that redirects are always `GET` requests and you don't seem to have a `GET` route for `/postca`.

Either change the redirect to a `GET` route or add a `Route::put('/postca', 'CAsController@.....');` route.